# How to display content from another domain by editing CNAME records?

Tags: dns, cname

I have a site that lets people have their own e-stores, for ex- **mysite.com/clientname**

What I want is, if somebody opens **store.clientname.com** or **clientname.com/store**, the content is pulled from **mysite.com/clientname**. [ So that their users feel that they are browsing on their site ]

I know this is possible because site'e like tumblr let you do that by changing a CNAME entry for your domain to their IP address.

I do have a dedicated IP address.

Also, can this be done by editing the .htaccess file at clientname.com, and if yes, which method is better/easy?

Comment: OK, I didn't know about ServerFault.com earlier. I will research this question there, and also keep this updated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to solve the problem in a completely different way for **http://store.clientname.com/** versus **http://clientname.com/store**.

In the first case, you can serve the web site as a virtual host. Just set up a virtual host called **store.clientname.com** and set its `DocumentRoot` to be the existing directory that contains the files for **http://mysite.com/clientname**. If you have other web server configuration directives that apply to **http://mysite.com/clientname** then you'll also want to apply those in the virtual host. Finally, the client can set up a CNAME record in DNS for **store.clientname.com** pointing to your web server.

If you are using Apache, you can also use a default virtual host and mod_rewrite to dynamically translate URLs of the form **http://store.{whatever}/** to **http://mysite.com/{whatever}/**. However, this won't work if you are using HTTPS.

In the second case, you don't want to serve the web site at **http://clientname.com/** because the client presumably is already hosting that and presumably **http://clientname.com/otherstuff** has to continue working and come from their server. So the second case is easier for you because all the work has to be done on the client's web server. But it's simple: they will just have to configure their web server to proxy **http://clientname.com/store** to **http://mysite.com/clientname**.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but could you explain/link to a resource for -
1. Setting up a virtual host.
2. Setting a server to proxy one site to another.

I know PHP and very basic web configuration. Maybe suggest a book?